# Preloading background images working in chrome but not working on firefox or IE

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer, firefox, preload

Preloading background images working in chrome but not working on firefox or IE.
I have a page that changes from a sequence of (background) images as the user scrolls - this should look like a video playing as the user scrolls down. It works perfectly in Google Chrome. But in firefox and IE the images flash onto the screen. I guess this is because the images are not preloaded, so they are loaded as the user scrolls.
To try preload the images I have done the following:
I have a loading screen until all the resources are loaded, this is done by:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

I also added the (background) images to a div in the document that is positioned off the screen:

```js
var totalImages = 50;

for (var i = 0; i < totalImages; i++) {
  var filename = 'images/video/london' + (i + 1) + '.jpg'; // Filename of each image
  // Array of images:
  var imageArray = [filename];

  jQuery('div#theDiv').prepend('<img src="' + imageArray + '" />');
}
```

```css
#theDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999em;
  left: -9999em;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv"></div>
```

Lastly I tried to preload the images with jQuery:

```js
var totalImages = 50;

for (var i = 0; i < totalImages; i++) {
  var filename = 'images/video/london' + (i + 1) + '.jpg'; // Filename of each image
  // Array of images:
  var imageArray = [filename];

  var count = 0,
    length = imageArray.length;

  $.each(imageArray, function(i, img) {
    var test = new Image();
    test.src = img.toString();
    $(test).on("load", function() {
      count++;
      if (count == length) {
        $(".loader").fadeOut();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: not sure if you're using PHP at all, but I would switch this to a PHP function. jQuery / Javascript usually isn't accessible until after the site loads any way (not all the time, but majority). If you force your images into the html (hidden the same) it should force the jquery to wait and when the site loads you'll have the correct effect.

Comment: @CayceK - javascript it is only available after the page fully loads if you use $(document).ready otherwise you can just use $(function () { directly after the elements that are referred to in your code block

Comment: @Ted Kinda struggling with something as I have not tested and don't have the ability right now, but what happens when you don't do either and just put the in without a wrapper. Doesn't it wait as if it had a $(document).ready?

Comment: @CayceK - the following causes an error:
`<script>
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'blah blah';
</script>
<div id='test'></div>`

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in the script you supplied. But before I furnish you with the entire finished code, let's walk through what you want to happen:

- Add 50 images to a hidden container on the page, so that they begin to load
- Wait for all 50 images to load
- Display the page

Here is how I would do this:

```js
// Wrapping a function with $() will wait until the page is ready

$(function() {

  // Find our target <div>s
  var preloader = $('#imagePreloader');
  var loadingCover = $('#loadingCover');

  var imageCount = 50;
  var loadedImages = 0;

  // For 1 to 50...
  var image;
  for (var i = 1; i <= imageCount; i++) {

    // Create a new <img>
    image = $('<img />', {
      src: '/path/to/your/images/' + i + '.jpg'
    });

    // Add an onload handler for the new image
    image.on('load', function() {
      if (++loadedImages === imageCount) {
        loadingCover.fadeOut();
      }
    });

    // Add the image to the page
    preloader.append(image);
  }
});
```

```css
#imagePreloader {
  position: absolute;
  top: -99999em;
  left: -99999em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="imagePreloader">
</div>

<div id="loadingCover">Loading...</div>
```

There is one caveat to bear in mind here - if any of the images fails to load, the loading cover will never be displayed. If you want to handle this case, you can add:

`image.on('error', function() { /* executed on error */ })`

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I'm a little confused by what you mean "after your <div id=test"> is defined" Do I need a div in my html file with a id of test?
I thought test was just a variable in the script

Comment: Sorry, I realise now that I mangled somebody else's comment into my answer. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: And again I've completely rewritten the answer for clarity. I shouldn't answer SO questions when I'm half asleep!

Comment: Hi. Thanks very much for your help. The problem has been resolved in IE, but I'm still having the same problem with firefox. The images still seem to flash onto the screen. Do you know why this may be? Also in the Network Monitor(in firefox's developer tools) the images are in the list - does this mean the images are preloaded? If so, why do they flash onto the screen like it's being loaded. Sorry for all the question - hope you can help. Thanks again